# WordPress plugin to make it more CMS-like by securing content

Tags: gratis, security, cms, wordpress

I'm trying to mold WordPress into a CMS. The main problem I'm currently facing is that I want to secure entire pages: most of the website won't be publicly available. I'm looking for a plugin (and possibly a theme recommendation, if a specific theme is required) to help me with this.

**Requirements**

- Ability to **create new roles** (*much* preferred) or tap into the existing WP roles, and adde users to those roles.
- Allows **restricting access to *Pages* to certain roles**: the page should not even show up in the menu, and if unauthorized users access the URL it should not show *anything* of that page (but an error message instead).
- Allows **restricting access to *Posts* to certain roles**: a post should not show up, even if unauthorized users access the URL directly (no post title, date, category; nothing).
- **Post restrictions should be on by default**: someone posting a new entry should *not* have to "remember" to secure the post. Preferably this is the case for Pages too, but that's a little less important as they're not created as frequently.
- These **restrictions should also hold for RSS feeds** on comments, posts, etc. (preferred), or there should be some other way to completely shut down these feeds. (Securing pages/posts is a bit useless if the RSS feeds still show this content.)
- It should **play nice with themes and popular plugins** (amongst others BBPress).
- The site should have **no registration**. An high level user should create the account.
- **Gratis**, i.e. free of charge.

In addition to one super user (website admin) there will be a handful of content editors/publishers, and several dozen of authorized users. These users will be created manually.

**What I've tried**

In WordPress land I've only tried three things:

- **The default user rights stuff.** This doesn't hold up to my requirements (no way to create roles or restrict viewing access at all).
- **The ["Members" plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).** Highly upvoted, looks like it has all of my requirements, but fails miserably on two important points. First, you can still see post info (title, date, categories, tags, author); only the post content is hidden. Second, it doesn't seem to play nice with BBPress: the page is still visible, with all basic info, and BBPress just says "Oh brother, no forums here". I might be using it wrong though...
- **The ["Groups" plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/)**. I'm currently trying this one out. Works okayish, but I'm having trouble (a) making posts secure by default, and (b) securing the RSS feeds if the content itself is secured.

In addition to that, I've tried Joomla! and have some experience with DotNetNuke. The first one is *better* than WordPress, but not quite to my taste as its terminology confuses me (which is exactly the reason I went back to WP). The latter is one I have more experience with, and works a bit more the way I had hoped WP would be able to behave.